# Making plot functions with ggplot and aes_string

Tags: r, ggplot2

In Hadley Wickham's **ggplot2** book in chapter 10.3, he alludes to making plot functions.  I want to make many similar plots that use faceting, but I cannot refer to a column.  If all my references are in aesthetics then I can use aes_string and everything works.  Facet_wrap seems not to have an analogue.

```
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)
```

This is the plot I want to functionalize.

```
pl.flower1 <- ggplot(data=iris, 
                    aes_string(x='Sepal.Length', y='Sepal.Width', color='Petal.Length')) +
                                 geom_point() +facet_wrap(~Species)
```

This works if I do not facet.

```
flowerPlot <- function(dat, sl, sw, pl, sp){
  ggplot(data=dat, aes_string(x=sl, y=sw, color=pl)) + geom_point()
}
pl.flower2 <- flowerPlot(iris, sl='Sepal.Length', sw='Sepal.Width', pl='Petal.Length')
```

What should "sp" be two lines below? A formula, a string?  Maybe the whole aproach is wrong.

```
flowerPlotWrap <- function(dat, sl, sw, pl, sp){
      ggplot(data=dat, aes_string(x=sl, y=sw, color=pl)) + geom_point() +facet_wrap(sp)
    }
    pl.flower3 <- flowerPlotWrap(iris, sl='Sepal.Length', sw='Sepal.Width', pl='Petal.Length', sp= ?????)
```

In addition to an answer I would love pointer on how anyone approaches this problem?

Comment: As for how to approach solving this question, I'd probably check on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043247/writing-r-functions-with-optional-arguments) first. :)

Comment: Also asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028353/passing-string-variable-facet-wrap-in-ggplot-using-r

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`facet_wrap` expects a formula as its first argument, so I'd just coerce it with `as.formula`, and feed in my `sp` as a string:

```
flowerPlotWrap <- function(dat, sl, sw, pl, sp){
      ggplot(data=dat, aes_string(x=sl, y=sw, color=pl)) + 
      geom_point() +facet_wrap(as.formula(sp)) # note the as.formula
}
pl.flower3 <- flowerPlotWrap(iris, sl='Sepal.Length', 
                             sw='Sepal.Width', pl='Petal.Length', 
                             sp= '~Species')
```

Alternatively if my formula was always going to look like `~[columnname]`, I could just build that in to `flowerPlotWrap` and pass in the column name:

```
flowerPlotWrap <- function(dat, sl, sw, pl, sp){
      ggplot(data=dat, aes_string(x=sl, y=sw, color=pl)) + 
      geom_point() +facet_wrap(as.formula(sprintf('~%s',sp)))
}
pl.flower3 <- flowerPlotWrap(iris, sl='Sepal.Length', 
                             sw='Sepal.Width', pl='Petal.Length', 
                             sp= 'Species')
```

(kudos to the reproducible example in your question! If everyone asked questions as well as that they'd get answers much quicker).

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer.  How did you figure out that facet_wrap expects a formula?

Comment: If you look at `?facet_wrap` it says `facet_wrap(facets,...)` and `facets: formula specifying variabls to facet by`.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some alternatives using new features from `ggplot2 V3.0.0`

Using strings :

```
flowerPlot <- function(dat, sl, sw, pl, sp){
  ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=!!ensym(sl), y=!!ensym(sw), color=!!ensym(pl))) + 
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(eval(expr(~!!ensym(sp))))
}

flowerPlot(iris, sl='Sepal.Length', sw='Sepal.Width', pl='Petal.Length', sp = 'Species')
```

Using names :

```
flowerPlot2 <- function(dat, sl, sw, pl, sp){
  ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=!!enquo(sl), y=!!enquo(sw), color=!!enquo(pl))) + 
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(eval(expr(~!!enquo(sp))))
}

flowerPlot2(iris, sl= Sepal.Length, sw=Sepal.Width, pl=Petal.Length, sp = Species)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function worked fine for me unmodified if I just used `sp='Species'`, i.e. the name of the variable you want to facet by.

`flowerPlotWrap(iris, sl='Sepal.Length', sw='Sepal.Width', pl='Petal.Length', sp='Species')`

[image]