# Passing string variable facet_wrap() in ggplot using R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a defined a variable named response.
this variable will be passed to facet_wrap() in ggplot package

```
 response<-"job"
```

When i specify variable directly  in facet_wrap()

e.g

```
   ggplot(data,aes(job,fill=class )) + geom_bar() +facet_wrap(~job)
```

it gives required plot

But when i specifying response variable in facet_wrap()

```
 ggplot(data,aes(job,fill=reponse))+ geom_bar() +  facet_wrap(~get(paste(response)))
```

i get error

```
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
```

Is there way where facet_wrap can accept variable name from response variable instead writing variable name directly in it

Comment: Could you make your example reproducible?

Comment: try `as.formula(paste("~", response))`

Comment: See here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028353/passing-string-variable-facet-wrap-in-ggplot-using-r

Comment: @PaulLemmens Your link just refers to this question again.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

(Turning @kohske's comment into an answer so that it can be accepted and "closed"):

```
facet_wrap(as.formula(paste("~", response)))
```