# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) - contradiction?

Tags: r, ggplot2

#### Edited to give a fuller example of code and specific issue

I'm writing a function to produce time series plots of stock prices.  However, I'm getting the following error

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'df1234' not found

Here's an example of the function:

```
plot.prices <- function(df1234) {
  require(ggplot2)
  g <- ggplot(df1234, aes(x= as.Date(Date, format= "%Y-%m-%d"), y= df1234[, 3], 
              colour= brewer.pal(12,"Set3")[1])) + geom_point(size=1)
  g + geom_point(aes(x= date, y = df1234[, 4], 
                 colour= brewer.pal(12,"Set3")[2]), size=1)

  # ... code not shown...
  g
}
```

And example data:

```
spy <- read.csv(file= 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY&d=11&e=1&f=2012&g=d&a=0&b=29&c=1993&ignore=.csv', header= T)

plot.prices(spy) # produces error
g <- ggplot(spy, aes(x= as.Date(Date, format= "%Y-%m-%d"), y= spy[, 3], 
              colour= brewer.pal(12,"Set3")[1])) + geom_point(size=1)
  g + geom_point(aes(x= as.Date(Date), y = spy[, 4], 
                 colour= brewer.pal(12,"Set3")[2]), size=1)
## does not produce error
```

As you can see, the code is identical. I get an error if the call to ggplot() is INSIDE the function but not if the call to ggplot() is OUTSIDE the function.

#### Anyone have any idea why the seeming contradiction?

Comment: You might be interested in [quantmod](http://www.quantmod.com/examples/intro/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is what you want, but it might help.  I modified agstudy's code:

```
spy <- read.csv(file= 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY&d=11&e=1&f=2012&g=d&a=0&b=29&c=1993&ignore=.csv', header= T)

library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

 plot.prices <- function(df) {

   df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format= "%Y-%m-%d")

   g <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x='Date', y= colnames(df)[3])) + 
                   geom_point(colour= brewer.pal(12,"Set3")[1], size=1)

   gg <- g + geom_point(aes_string(x='Date', y= colnames(df)[4]),
                   colour= brewer.pal(12,"Set3")[2], size=1)
   gg
 }

 plot.prices(spy)
```

Here is code without using `brewer.pal`:

```
library(ggplot2)

spy <- read.csv(file= 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY&d=11&e=1&f=2012&g=d&a=0&b=29&c=1993&ignore=.csv', header= T)

 plot.prices <- function(df) {

   df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format= "%Y-%m-%d")

   g <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x='Date', y= colnames(df)[3])) + 
                   geom_point(colour= 'green', fill='green', size=1)

   gg <- g + geom_point(aes_string(x='Date', y= colnames(df)[4]),
                   colour= 'black', fill='black', size=1)
   gg
 }

 plot.prices(spy)
```

Comment: Looks like I had a syntax error. I was using "... aes_string(x,y, **colour**)" not "... aes_string(x,y **), colour**)"

Answer (score 10):

The error occur because you use df[, 7] in gglpot2, use column name  Adj.Close will fix the problem.

```
 g <- ggplot(df, aes(x= as.Date(Date, format= "%Y-%m-%d"),
                  y= Adj.Close)) + geom_point(size=1)
```

In fact the error , it is a scoping error. **aes** can't find the df environnement. It tries to look for it the global scope .

if you you want to use use indexing calls , you can use **aes_string** for example , and manipulate strings not expressions

```
plot.prices <- function(df) {
  require(ggplot2)

  df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format= "%Y-%m-%d")

  g <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x= 'Date',
                      y= colnames(df)[7])) + geom_point(size=1)

  # ... code not shown...
  g
}
```

[image]

Comment: This would fix the problem in the example function. However, the full code includes adding layers for multiple columns.... I didn't put the full detail because it would make the example data difficult. <\n>

**Bottom Line** I need to be able to use indexing calls for the aes(y= ...) call.

Comment: @Alex I append my solution for indexing

Comment: I edited my problem to give a fuller example of the error. Perhaps the issue is the addition of colour= brewer.pal(...)

Comment: Where did you get brewer.pal?  Is it in the 'RColorBrewer' package?

Comment: @Alex before trying to do complex plots with ggplot2 try to understand the basics : aesthetic mapping and the lexical scoping.

Comment: For parameterizing col names in ggplot functions, see also [Making plot functions with ggplot and aes_string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004847/making-plot-functions-with-ggplot-and-aes-string). If you stored the column `as.Date(Date, format= "%Y-%m-%d")` then you could use `aes_string` to reference both x,y series.