# Shiny - FILL value not passed to ggplot correctly in shiny server - error object 'input' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, heatmap, shiny

I am trying to develop a shiny app that will mount a map based heat map on a browser and allow you to change the variable shown on the heat map. The map is of a geographic region with GIS shape files and the variable chosen is then shown on the map as a heat map. Unfortunately I have a problem in that the variable is not being passed to `ggplot()` correctly and my map fails. The server.r code below as a straight R script runs successfully without issue but when adapted to Shiny it fails.

The issue happens with the following `ggplot()` code in server.r:

```
myplot1 <- myplot1 + aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = input$var) + ...
```

I get an error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'input' not found

This has to do with `fill = input$var` where it does not recognize `input$var` that is being passed from ui.r. `input$var` is the chosen variable (var1, var2, etc.) in ui.r to show on the heat map. This is the only instance I know of in the code where `input$var` is not recognized. I have used `print(str(input$var))` before this line and it clearly holds the desired variable's name. If I hard code it in (e.g. `fill=var1`), then `ggplot()` works fine and the map is shown correctly.

I have also used `environment = environment()` in the `ggplot()` but this generates another error:

> Error : Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

I am interpreting to mean that it is looking for a data frame described by the variable but instead it gets a single value.

I get the feeling that it is something simple I am missing - something I should declare or re-assign. I would be grateful for any insight, guidance or feedback folks have on this. Many thanks !!

```
# server.R

library(shiny)

library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(sp)
library(maptools)
library(scales)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgeos)
library(plyr)
library(reshape)
library(mapproj)
library(rgdal)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

setwd("C:/Shiny")


# Step 1 Read/loading the target shapefile
gregion = readOGR(dsn="C:/Shiny", layer="duid")

# Step 2 Get row numbers from .dbf / explicitly identifies attribute rows by the .dbf offset.
gregion@data$id = rownames(gregion@data)

# Step 3 Makes centroid (point layer) from polygon "FORTIFY"
gregion.points = fortify(gregion, region="id")

# Step 4 Reading in .csv which will be joined to .dbf using "MERGE"
mydata <- read.csv("c:/Shiny/dataset.txt")

# Step 5 Joins the points to their corresponding attributes and finalizes the data preparation 
gregion.df = join(gregion.points, gregion@data, by="id")

# Step 6 Merge makes an inner join of the shapefile's data frame and the .csv on a common item (usually the spatial key)
mygeomdata <- merge(gregion.df, mydata, by.x="UID", by.y="UID")


# Define server logic required to plot various variables as heatmap
# Step 7 Create map
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Compute the forumla text in a reactive expression since it is 
  # shared by the output$caption and output$mapPlot expressions

  formulaText <- reactive({
    paste("Variable:", input$var)
  })

  # Return the formula text for printing as a caption
  output$caption <- renderText({
    formulaText()
  })


  output$mapPlot <- renderPlot({

    myplot1 <- ggplot(mygeomdata)
    myplot1 <- myplot1 + aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = input$var) + labs(x = "Easting", y = "Northing") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "ghostwhite", high = "steelblue")
    myplot1 <- myplot1 + geom_polygon()
    myplot1 <- myplot1 + coord_equal()

    print(myplot1)

  })

})

#ui.R

library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("Mapping"),

  # Sidebar with controls to select the variable to plot
  #

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("var", "Variable:",
                list("Variable 1" = "var1",
                     "Variable 2" = "var2"))
  ),

  # Show the caption and plot of the requested variable

  mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("caption")),

    plotOutput("mapPlot")
  )
))
```

A sample of the dataset, `mydata <- read.csv("c:/Shiny/dataset.txt")` is:

```
UID var1    var2    var3    var4    var5    var6    var7
1   0   0.001   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   0   0.004   0.026   0   0   0   0
9   0.499   0.014   0   0.499   1   0   0.033
10  0.573   0.002   0.015   0.573   1   0   0.427
11  1   0.003   0.01    1   1   0   0
```

`mygeomdata` has the following structure:

```
 $ UID       : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ long      : num  393121 392895 392895 392840 392839 ...
 $ lat       : num  5501404 5502275 5502275 5502489 5502494 ...
 $ order     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ hole      : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ piece     : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ group     : Factor w/ 5693 levels "0.1","1.1","10.1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ id        : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
 $ DUID      : Factor w/ 5656 levels "130023362","130023367",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PC        : Factor w/ 3617 levels "0","ZZZ0A3","ZZZ0A4",..: 3271 3271 3271 3271 3271 3271 3271 3271 3271 3271 ...
 $ DUIDAREA  : num  21687 21687 21687 21687 21687 ...
 $ ELEV      : num  14.8 14.8 14.8 14.8 14.8 ...
 $ GroupUp   : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ GroupUpT  : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ var1      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ var2      : num  0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 ...
 $ var3      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ var4      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ var5      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ var6      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ var7      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Ram Narasimhan. You pointed me to some very useful posts and I was able to after some digging arrive at a solution. Here is the modified section:

```
environment<-environment() 
  myplot1 <- ggplot(mygeomdata, aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = get(input$var)), environment = environment)
```

The above code is placed outside of the renderPlot call.
Many thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Even though you are getting this error as part of your attempt to port it to Shiny, this is related to `ggplot`. In a nutshell, you are using local variables and function arguments to `aes` and that is trickier than it first seems.

Please see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659133/local-variables-within-aes?rq=1) for a full discussion and several good options.

One thing to keep in mind: For ggplot, to the extent that you keep everything needed as part of the data frame, you will find it that much easier.

[agstudy's response in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664585/error-in-evalexpr-envir-enclos-contradiction) explains what is going on.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Ram Narasimhan. You pointed me to some very useful posts and I was able to after some digging arrive at a solution. Here is the modified section - see below in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a simpler solution. Use ggplot() within the renderPlot() function as you did before, but use aes_string() instead of aes():

```
output$mapPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mygeomdata, aes_string(x=long, y=lat, group = group, fill = input$var)) + geom_point()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)` also works. Just make sure that both inputs are taken as reactive inputs (e.g. `input$`). `ggplot()` isn't allowing one of the axes to be manual and the other as reactive.

Comment: This is a valid answer on its own.  However, it duplicates an existing answer from 2 months ago.