# Error in trying to write a plotting function in ggplot2

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I am trying to write a function in ggplot2 and obtain this error message:

> Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) :
>     At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting

Here is my code:

```
growth.plot<-function(data,x,y,fac){ 
gp <- ggplot(data = data,aes(x = x, y = y)) 
gp <- gp + geom_point()  + facet_wrap(~ fac)
return(gp)
}

growth.plot(data=mydata, x=x.var, y=y.var,fac= fac.var)
```

If I try without the function, the plot appears perfectly

```
gp1 <- ggplot(data = mydata,aes(x = x.var), y = y.var))
gp1+ geom_point()+ facet_wrap(~ fac.var) # this works
```

Comment: Have a look at `aes_string`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but unfortunatelly it does not work.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10004944/2461552) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is reproducible solution where your x, y, and fac arguments must be passed as character:

```
library(ggplot2)

make_plot = function(data, x, y, fac) {
    p = ggplot(data, aes_string(x=x, y=y, colour=fac)) +
        geom_point(size=3) +
        facet_wrap(as.formula(paste("~", fac)))
    return(p)
}

p = make_plot(iris, x="Sepal.Length", y="Petal.Length", fac="Species")

ggsave("iris_plot.png", plot=p, height=4, width=8, dpi=120)
```

[image]

Thanks to commenters @Roland and @aosmith for pointing the way to this solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. Never easy to find its way through the small R subtleties.