# ggplot2's aes_string() does not like "rownames(mtcars)" when inside a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to generate a plot inside a function, relying on `aes_string()`, and I need labels as rownames.

The below plot works fine, but **not inside a function**.

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
plotfun <- function(cars) {
  g <- ggplot(data = cars, aes_string(x = "mpg", y = "disp", label = "rownames(cars)"))
  g <- g + geom_point()
  g <- g + geom_text()
  g
}
plotfun(cars = mtcars)
```

When run as a function, that gets me:

```
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:mpg, disp
```

I can't wrap my head around it.
I am aware that there are plenty of [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004847/making-plot-functions-with-ggplot-and-aes-string) about `aes_string()` inside a function –– I just wasn't able to adapt their solutions to my problem.

Ps.: obviously, the above MWE is pretty stupid; in my real use-case, I run the plot through for loops, hence the need for `aes_string()`.

Comment: i would just use the rownames and create a new column and move on

Comment: yup, thought about that – does not work in my case, because said for loop loops over the *columns*  of that df ... so I can't "pollute" it with other columns.
Also namespace headaches there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you would be better served by `aes_q` here rather than `aes_string`

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
plotfun <- function(cars) {
  g <- ggplot(data = cars, aes_q(x = as.name("mpg"), y = as.name("disp"), label=rownames(cars)))
  g <- g + geom_point()
  g <- g + geom_text()
  g
}
plotfun(cars = mtcars)
```

The `aes_q` allows you to pass unevaluated symbols and calls so we just use `as.name()` to convert your strings into symbols that can later be evaluated in your data.

Comment: fantastic; did not know about `aes_q()`. 
Seems to be a recent addition, right? It's not on http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/index.html, but *is* on CRAN already.

Comment: @maxheld apparently [since 1.0](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/efddff695a7b78ac26666afa994f7db834e6464a/NEWS#L194:L196)

Answer (score 4):

Using it inside of deparse seems to work with `aes_string`:

```
plotfun <- function(cars) {
  g <- ggplot(data = cars, aes_string(x = "mpg", y = "disp", 
              label = deparse(rownames(cars))))
  g <- g + geom_point()
  g <- g + geom_text()
  g
}

plotfun(cars = mtcars)
```

[image]

For some additional info `deparse` will turn unevaluated expressions i.e. (`rownames(cars)`) into character strings which means in case of `mtcars`:

```
> deparse(rownames(mtcars))
[1] "c(\"Mazda RX4\", \"Mazda RX4 Wag\", \"Datsun 710\", \"Hornet 4 Drive\", "         
[2] "\"Hornet Sportabout\", \"Valiant\", \"Duster 360\", \"Merc 240D\", \"Merc 230\", "
[3] "\"Merc 280\", \"Merc 280C\", \"Merc 450SE\", \"Merc 450SL\", \"Merc 450SLC\", "   
[4] "\"Cadillac Fleetwood\", \"Lincoln Continental\", \"Chrysler Imperial\", "         
[5] "\"Fiat 128\", \"Honda Civic\", \"Toyota Corolla\", \"Toyota Corona\", "           
[6] "\"Dodge Challenger\", \"AMC Javelin\", \"Camaro Z28\", \"Pontiac Firebird\", "    
[7] "\"Fiat X1-9\", \"Porsche 914-2\", \"Lotus Europa\", \"Ford Pantera L\", "         
[8] "\"Ferrari Dino\", \"Maserati Bora\", \"Volvo 142E\")"
```

which as a character vector can be easily evaluated inside of `aes_string`.